# Apache Reverse Proxy 404 errors when resources loaded from root context path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy, reverse-proxy

Seeing an issue after configuring a reverse proxy in my Apache web server and having a tough time finding a solution, hoping one of you may be able to assist.

Example:

I am trying to configure a reverse proxy to map the backend application URL http://appserver/app/ to the URL https://webserver/app/ on my public domain.

I noticed that any resources located under the http://appserver/app/ path (such as /app/images) are being served properly when accessed via corresponding reverse proxy URL (https://webserver/app/images).

However, some html files are being served from the backend application server root context path (http://appserver/test.html) and the requests for these files are returning 404 errors when the application is accessed via the reverse proxy URL

When reviewing the chrome dev tools network trace, I see Apache is serving these resources from the root context of the reverse proxy URL (https://webserver/test.html), instead of the reverse proxy path (https://webserver/app/test.html), as intended.

I believe this is the expected behavior in Apache, but I am trying to find a way to rewrite the URLs to serve these resources via the reverse proxy context path https://webserver/app/ instead of the root.

Below is my current configuration and I am aware that it will not work as intended when configured this way, but I have tried just about every combination of RewriteRule and ProxyPassReverse directives I can think of, to no avail.

`RewriteRule ^/app/(.*)$ http://appserver/app/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://appserver/app/`

I have also tried the following, with no luck.

`RewriteRule ^/app/(.*)$ http://appserver/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://appserver/`

Outside of the basics, I am a bit of a noob when it comes to Apache, so I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I have looked all over to find a solution, and still haven't found one :(

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks a lot